# Running docker command from php

Tags: php, docker, terminal

I'm using php 7.3.

I tried to run a docker command from server, but failed.

Note that, if I run this command:

```
exec('OUTPUT=`sudo docker ps`;echo $OUTPUT;', $output, $return_var);
```

it runs successfully, and returning this message :

```
"CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES"
```

it means the user running my web server can run docker commands.

PS: I don't have any running container at the moment, I just want to execute the `docker run` command.

---

But, if I run the docker command, using  :

```
exec('OUTPUT=`docker run -ti --rm -v /server-path:/pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 20200818075525_634.pdf`;echo $OUTPUT;', $output, $return_var);
```

the output is an empty string, and no HTML file generated.

Strangely if I run the command directly in the terminal :

```
OUTPUT=`docker run -ti --rm -v /server-path:/pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 20200818075525_634.pdf`;echo $OUTPUT;
```

the command is executed and I can see the pdf file has been converted to HTML successfully.

[image: uploaded pdf file folder]

PS: I run the command twice in the terminal, thus there are 2 generated HTML files.

and the debug console is displaying this :

[image: debug console]

PS: `root` is the user running the webserver, I get this user by executing `get_current_user()`, and `return_var` the third parameter returned by `exec`

---

I tried another way, to test the `docker run` command, by running this :

```
exec('OUTPUT=`docker run --rm -w /pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex whoami`;echo $OUTPUT;', $output, $return_var);
```

and it returned `root` as the output, it means the `docker run` was run successfully, so there's no problem with running that command.

[image: docker run result]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked for the exit code returned by `exec`? Have you checked whether the user running your webserver is able to run Docker commands after all?

Comment: Yes, I have, the exit code is 0, the user running my webserver is able to run docker commands, as you can see, if I run docker ps, it runs successfully, so there should be no problem when running the docker commands

Comment: The main difference seems to be that your first command (the one that works) is using `sudo`

Comment: nope, even if I remove the sudo, it still works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, and I just wanna let anyone know in case someone encounters the same issue.

I decided to remove some parameters and then see what would happen next, and finally, I found out the `-ti` was the culprit.

So, I changed this :

```
exec('OUTPUT=`docker run -ti --rm -v /server-path:/pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 20200818075525_634.pdf`;echo $OUTPUT;', $output, $return_var);
```

to :

```
exec('OUTPUT=`docker run --rm -v /server-path:/pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 20200818075525_634.pdf`;echo $OUTPUT;', $output, $return_var);
```

and finally, the HTML file was generated.

Not sure why the `-ti` caused the issue, I only did what was suggested by the official page [here](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/wiki/Download).

But, anyway, problem solved :)

Comment: I've experienced this before on my build servers.  Someone will probably be able to explain this better than me, but here's a start… the reason this wasn't working with the -i & -t flags was probably because you were running the command in an environment that isn't able to connect a pseudo-TTY to the container..

Comment: This is a great explanation of the TTY and it's history… https://www.howtogeek.com/428174/what-is-a-tty-on-linux-and-how-to-use-the-tty-command/